# Polynomials with nondegenerate critical points and their derivatives

Tags: polynomials, singularity-theory, coprime

I have the following problem (it arises in a calculation in Topological String Theory in the paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0404184) that the author glosses over when evaluating a spectral sequence, but condenses down to this assertion):

Let $W \in \mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ be a complex polynomial with nondegenerate critical points, i.e. at every point $x\in \mathbb{C}^n$ where all the (formal) partial derivatives $\partial_i W$ are $0$, the Hesse matrix of $W$ is nondegenerate (i.e. invertible). What the Author seems to use in a calculation is that then, the sequence $\partial_1 W, \dots, \partial_n W$ in  $\mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ is regular (which helps evaluate the Koszul cohomology of a certain chain complex). To spell this out, e.g. $\partial_1 W$ should not be a zero divisor in $\mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots, x_n]/(\partial_2 W, \dots, \partial_n W)$, and the same for all other derivatives.

In all examples I tried out, this seemed to be true; however I can't find an actual proof of this (maybe it is a standard fact of singularity theory?). Maybe it isn't even true, but I could show that the statement made in the above paper wouldn't hold then, so it should better be...

Comment: An idea would be to use a translation to choose $x=0$, and to bring $W$ to sylvester form by a linear automorphism of $\mathbb{C}^n$. I think in this case, one would be able to show ealily that W having nondegenerate singularities and the sequence of derivatives being regular would even be equivalent. However, as there might be multiple singularities of $W$, I am not sure if this is without loss of generality, or what happens if $W$ has no singularity at all.

Comment: If $W$ is linear non-constant, then it has no critical points, but the ideal of the partial derivatives is the whole space of polynomials, so in the quotient everything is zero..

Comment: @Exodd That shouldn't be not problem, as $0$ is not a zero divisor in the $0$ ring. I've found a different reference that actually stated what I am claiming here, so it should be correct (see [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=I9ZTDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA359&lpg=PA359&dq=jacobian+ring+koszul+complex+isolated+singularity&source=bl&ots=Ud9TqRFyRb&sig=ACfU3U1roIJoCcorYgdbU82kA4pN618Kqw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiNgtKwwJrqAhVGtIsKHWc4BBwQ6AEwAXoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=jacobian%20ring%20koszul%20complex%20isolated%20singularity&f=false), Google Link as it will be hard to find otherwise...)

Comment: Also found an algebraic geometry book where this is stated. By idea proposed in the first comment however does not work, even though it certainly does make the situation easier...

Comment: Also, depending on how "zero divisor" is defined, some books also assume that the Jacobi ring $\mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots, x_n]/(\partial_1 W, \dots, \partial_n W)$ is not the zero ring. There further seems to be a more general proof of my statement using Cohen-Macaulay rings, that I however haven't found spelled out, I would also be happy about an explanation of this.